# Proving that a function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic function, for an open $U$ and $f'$ continous. If $|f(z)-1|<1 \forall z \in U$, then, $\int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=0$ for all closed curve $\gamma \in C^1$

I thought about defining a map $g(z):=\log (f(z))$, since we would have that $g'(z)= \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$. I also know that it is enough to show that $g'(z)$ is holomorphic, but is was as far as I went. Could anyone give a hand?

Comment: You can define a holomorphic branch of the logarithm on $\operatorname{re} z > 0$.

Comment: For the record, this is directly a special case of the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the image of $f$ is contained in the right half plane, and there is a branch of logarithm in this domain. So you can indeed define $g(z)=log(f(z))$, this is a primitive of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$. And if a function has a primitive in some neighborhood of $\gamma$ then it is enough. If $\gamma: [a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ then $\int_{\gamma} g'(z)dz=g(\gamma(b))-g(\gamma(a))$. Since $\gamma$ is a closed curve we have $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$, and hence:

$\int_{\gamma} g'(z)dz=g(\gamma(a))-g(\gamma(a))=0$